# Почему в VS2008 Professional в отличие от VS2008 Express, нельзя на 1 кнопку забиндить 2 действия?

Tags: visual-studio

Пример: На кнопку F2 забиндить одновременно "открыть файл", "перейти к определению функции". VS понимает объект на котором курсор, и выберет действие объекту соответствующее. Подобная логика также реализована в JetBrains, это не ошибка Express версии.